# What is the difference between the rename options

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015

When you edit a build definition you have the possibility to edit the auto generated name of the build task.

Below the task name there are two links: Reset and Generate.
Both of them are putting back the task name to the initial value.

What's the difference between them?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is still a bit difference between `reset` and `generate`.

---

For example, as below scenario

[image]

Have changed the name to `Powershell:user`, then edit it to user123, not saved.

Click **generate**: The name in the dialog will change to `Powershell:patrick` and click ok, it will also saved as `Powershell:patrick`.

Click **reset**: The name in the dialog will change to `Powershell:user`. However, when your click ok , it will saved as `Powershell:patrick`.

---

It's weird, the display and the save are inconsistent. It doesn't make sense, the function of two options are exactly the same.Looks like a bug. Not sure what's the original function of reset option.

Have committed this information to development group through the internal tools. Will updated here, once receive a reply.